# html5 video player remove black shadow at bottom of controls section

Tags: php, html, css, video, html5-video

**Hi,**

I have an HTML 5 Video Player on my website. Whenever I click pause or hover the video the strange black shadow appears. It's overlaying the control section. How can I get rid of that. I tried to search solution for this, but I couldn't find the solution. Please help me with this.

[image: black-shadow-image]

Comment: Please fix your Markdown formatting.  Please include your actual code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The webkit pseudo element for video control panel is

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-panel
```

To set or update this element you just add this css

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
  // Your styling here
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent) !important; //Transparent for your case

}
```

Also, make sure you mark your styling as important. A friendly reminder that you may need to set this property on your target/selected element to get the styling results you want:

-webkit-appearance:none;

Refer more [on this gist](https://gist.github.com/afabbro/3759334)

Answer (score 3):

This is the code that worked for me, try.

```css
    video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
         background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent) !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add css like this

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
   background-color: transparent !important;
   box-shadow: none !important
}
```

You could also use other pseudo in css to control the native video like

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display {}
```

Comment: i have tied it Urek Mazino.. Still Not Working